# How do I download a particular file from GitHub?

Tags: github

I only need one particular file from a project published on GitHub so it makes little sense to download the whole project. But I just can't find the download button.

Comment: [Download single files from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4604663/6521116)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're viewing the contents of the file itself there should be a "Raw" button.

> [image: get raw]

You can either:

- Right-click on that and select the "Save content as..." (or similar depending on your browser)
- Click through to see the contents dumped onto the screen and save from there

Answer (score 8):

In the list of files, every filename is a link. A simple right-click and "Save link as..." (or equivalent for your browser) will allow you to download a single file.

This breaks down with HTML files, however. You'll need to use the "Raw" button on the file page as [Eight Days of Malaise's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/87957/354) describes. I'm using Google Chrome. You may have a different experience on a different browser.

Comment: Those links go the the html page for that file, not the file itself. (Unless you're referring to another file list, in which case you should extend your answer to describe how to get to that file list)

Comment: @CodesInChaos: It works just fine. Yes, if you just click the link it will open GitHub's page for that file, but "Save link as..." saves the file in its "native format".

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with HTML files.

Comment: @Zenadix: So it does. I've updated my answer.

Comment: For me it never works (Using Firefox). It always downloads github's html page for that file.

Comment: @Codes: I'm using Chrome, so maybe that has something to do with it. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Tested it in chrome and it doesn't work either. The downloaded file still contains html. Did you check the *content* of the file?

Comment: @Codes: Well I don't know what the difference could be. It works great for me (and apparently other people).

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Do you have any sort of script blocker? I'm pretty sure there's more than just HTML going on here. This could even be turned into a decent question.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [RawGit](http://rawgit.com/) which is a free service to serve files directly from Github with proper Content-type headers.

Example URL:
https://rawgit.com/user/repo/branch/file

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Chromium browser, just hold down the ALT key and left click on the file to download it.

(Doesn't work with Mozilla Firefox, haven't tested other browsers.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [github-files-fetcher](https://github.com/Gyumeijie/github-files-fetcher), it is a command line tool which downloads a single folder or file from a GitHub repo.

Think a real scenario: you were visiting the following webpage page and wanna download the `async` subdirectory alone.

[image: redux]

With The `github-files-fetcher`, you should first copy the `url` of that page, which is https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async, and then run the command below in command line:

`fetcher --url=https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async`